# $(X_n ; n>0)$ gaussian random variable sequence, converges uniformly, implies that $X_n$ converges in $L^2$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $(X_n ; n>0)$ a gaussian random variables sequence.
$X_n$ converges to $X$ Uniformaly ie $\sup\limits_{\omega\in\Omega}|X_n-X|$ converges to $0$.
We Must prove that : $$E((X_n-X)^2)$$ converges to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Bounded Convergence Theorem,

$$E[|X_n-X|^2]\leq \Big(\sup_{\Omega }|X_n-X|\Big)^2.$$

Comment: How to prove it.

Comment: @BoualiAnas: May be you can try, it's very easy to prove it ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I just need the expression of $E((X_n-X)^2)$

Comment: But you can't have it since you even dont know what is $X_n$. And it anyway wouldn't help to solve your exercise...

Comment: I dont know, which inequality we should use. Could you please, tell me how to start. and thanks

Comment: It's just a property of the expectation : $$X\leq Y\implies \mathbb E[X]\leq \mathbb E[Y].$$

Comment: So if this property is true, we can use also if $X_n$ converges uniformaly implies $X_n$ converges in probability. Then $$P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)$$ converges to 0. then we have $|X_n-X|<\epsilon$ then $|X_n-X|^2<\epsilon^2$ then $E(|X_n-X|^2)< \epsilon^2$.

Comment: Not at all ! Why do you complicate a such easy thing ? $$|X_n-X|\leq \sup_\Omega  |X_n-X|\implies |X_n-X|^2\leq (\sup_{\Omega }|X_n-X|)^2\implies \mathbb E[|X_n-X|^2]\leq (\sup_{\Omega }|X_n-X|)^2.$$ Finish !

Comment: thanks, i get it